# how do i reference a cursor defined in a database via another database's stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a cursor as part of a process that removes the files of a specified database file group.  I want to code this in a stored procedure that will exist in one database and reference another database.

When I code the open cursor command with use [@DBName]; open file_cursor cursor, I receive "Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 10 Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'cursor'"

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Add your code to help you

Comment: Did you try DB_Name.dbo.cursor_name(3 part identifier) instead of changing database? dbo could be replaced with your schema name.

Answer (score 0):

use dynamic sql for entire cursor code ; declare, open fetch next
-- Example

use dba
go
create procedure usp_listtables @dbname varchar(50)
as
set nocount on

declare @sql varchar(max)
set @sql= 'use '+ @dbname + '; select * from sys.tables'
exec(@sql)

go

use dba
exec

exec  usp_listtables 'dbb'